# How to get deterministic behavior in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a very basic model training on MNIST, and I'd like to make the training process deterministic.

I've set all of these seeds mentioned in other posts:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

tf.random.set_seed(12)
np.random.seed(12)
random.seed(12)

initializer = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=12)
```

And my model is the following:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros())
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)
```

But I still see non-deterministic behavior from

```
model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=ds_test,
    callbacks=[callback],
    shuffle=False, use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

Would appreciate any help with this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error, when I replicated these same codes with `MNIST` dataset in `Google Colab` with `Tensorflow ==2.7`.

```
model.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    #callbacks=[callback],
    shuffle=False, use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/2
1875/1875 [==============================] - 13s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2687 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9232 - val_loss: 0.1686 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9460
Epoch 2/2
1875/1875 [==============================] - 10s 5ms/step - loss: 0.1215 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9646 - val_loss: 0.1375 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9561
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f51a89480d0>
```

Let us know the `traceback` error you are getting and which `Tensorflow` are you using to be specific for replicating and fix this issue.